# Why is Wordpress update_user_meta() not working for custom form?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, registration

Hello i found a custom form for Wordpress that i wanted to extend by some inputs (street, postalcode, ustid, country, phonenumber). By default wp_insert_user() can only have certain keys (like user_login, user_pass...). So inputs like address and USt-iD for the billing/shippindadress need to be updated with update_user_meta() (if there is a simpler way i would appreciate an answer):

```
function red_registration_form($atts) {
     $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'role' => 'subscriber',         
    ), $atts, 'register' );
    
$role_number = $atts["role"];
 if ($role_number == "shop_manager" ) { $reg_form_role = (int) filter_var(AUTH_KEY, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); }  elseif ($role_number == "customer" ) { $reg_form_role = (int) filter_var(SECURE_AUTH_KEY, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); } elseif ($role_number == "contributor" ) { $reg_form_role = (int) filter_var(NONCE_KEY, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); } elseif ($role_number == "author" ) { $reg_form_role = (int) filter_var(AUTH_SALT, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); } elseif ($role_number == "editor" ) { $reg_form_role = (int) filter_var(SECURE_AUTH_SALT, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); }   elseif ($role_number == "administrator" ) { $reg_form_role = (int) filter_var(LOGGED_IN_SALT, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); } else { $reg_form_role = 1001; } 
    
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) { 
        $registration_enabled = get_option('users_can_register');
        if($registration_enabled) {
            $output = red_registration_fields($reg_form_role);
        } else {
            $output = __('<p>User registration is not enabled</p>');
        }
        return $output;
    }  $output = __('<p>You already have an account on this site, so there is no need to register again.</p>');
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('register', 'red_registration_form');

function red_registration_fields($reg_form_role) {  ?> 
<?php
    ob_start();
    ?>  
        <form id="red_registration_form" class="red_form" action="" method="POST">
                <?php red_register_messages();   ?>
                <p>
                    <label for="red_user_login"><?php _e('Username'); ?></label>
                    <input name="red_user_login" id="red_user_login" class="red_input" placeholder="Benutzername" type="text"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="red_user_company"><?php _e('Firma'); ?></label>
                    <input name="red_user_company" id="red_user_company" class="red_input" placeholder="Firma" type="text" required/>
                </p>            
                <p>
                    <label for="red_user_email"><?php _e('Email'); ?></label>
                    <input name="red_user_email" id="red_user_email" class="red_input" placeholder="Email" type="email" required/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="red_user_first"><?php _e('First Name'); ?></label>
                    <input name="red_user_first" id="red_user_first" type="text" placeholder="Vorname" class="red_input" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="red_user_last"><?php _e('Last Name'); ?></label>
                    <input name="red_user_last" id="red_user_last" type="text" placeholder="Nachname" class="red_input"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="red_user_street"><?php _e('Street'); ?></label>
                    <input name="red_user_street" id="red_user_street" type="text" placeholder="Straße" class="red_input" required/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="red_user_postal_code"><?php _e('Postal Code'); ?></label>
                    <input name="red_user_postal_code" id="red_user_postal_code" type="number" placeholder="Postleitzahl" class="red_input" required/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="red_user_ustid"><?php _e('USt-ID'); ?></label>
                    <input name="red_user_ustid" id="red_user_ustid" type="text" placeholder="USt-ID Nr" class="red_input" required/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="red_user_website"><?php _e('Website'); ?></label>
                    <input name="red_user_website" id="red_user_website" type="text" placeholder="Webseite" class="red_input"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="red_user_phonenumber"><?php _e('Phonenumber'); ?></label>
                    <input name="red_user_phonenumber" id="red_user_phonenumber" type="tel" placeholder="Telefonnummer" class="red_input"/>
                </p>        
                <p>
                    <label for="password"><?php _e('Password'); ?></label>
                    <input name="red_user_pass" id="password" class="red_input" placeholder="Password" type="password" required/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password_again"><?php _e('Password'); ?></label>
                    <input name="red_user_pass_confirm" id="password_again" placeholder="Password Again" class="red_input" type="password" required/>
                </p>
                <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="red_csrf" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('red-csrf'); ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="red_role" value="<?php echo $reg_form_role; ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Register Now'); ?>"/>
                </p>
            
        </form>  
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
function red_add_new_user() {
    if (isset( $_POST["red_user_login"] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['red_csrf'], 'red-csrf')) {
      $user_login       = sanitize_user($_POST["red_user_login"]);
      $user_company     = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_company"]);
      $user_email       = sanitize_email($_POST["red_user_email"]);
      $user_first       = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_first"] );
      $user_last        = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_last"] );
      $user_street      = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_street"]);
      $user_postal_code = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_postal_code"]);
      $user_country     = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_country"]);
      $user_ustid       = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_ustid"]);
      $user_website     = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_website"]);
      $user_phone       = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_phonenumber"]);
      $user_pass        = $_POST["red_user_pass"];
      $pass_confirm     = $_POST["red_user_pass_confirm"];
      $red_role         = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_role"] );    
      
    if ($red_role == (int) filter_var(AUTH_KEY, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ) { $role = "shop_manager"; }  elseif ($red_role == (int) filter_var(SECURE_AUTH_KEY, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ) { $role = "customer"; } elseif ($red_role == (int) filter_var(NONCE_KEY, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ) { $role = "contributor"; } elseif ($red_role == (int) filter_var(AUTH_SALT, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)  ) { $role = "author"; } elseif ($red_role ==  (int) filter_var(SECURE_AUTH_SALT, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ) { $role = "editor"; }   elseif ($red_role == (int) filter_var(LOGGED_IN_SALT, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ) { $role = "administrator"; } else { $role = "subscriber"; }
      
      if(username_exists($user_login)) {
          red_errors()->add('username_unavailable', __('Dieser Benutzername ist bereits vergeben'));
      }
      if(!validate_username($user_login)) {
          red_errors()->add('username_invalid', __('Ungültiger Benutzername'));
      }
      if($user_login == '') {
          red_errors()->add('username_empty', __('Bitte geben sie einen Benutzernamen ein'));
      }
      if($user_company == '') {
          red_errors()->add('company_empty', __('Bitte geben sie eine Firma ein'));
      }
      if($user_street == '') {
          red_errors()->add('street_empty', __('Bitte geben sie eine Straße ein'));
      }
      if($user_postal_code == '') {
          red_errors()->add('postal_code_empty', __('Bitte geben sie eine Postleitzahl ein'));
      }
      if($user_country == '') {
          red_errors()->add('country_empty', __('Bitte geben sie ein Land ein'));
      }
      if($user_ustid == '') {
          red_errors()->add('ustid_empty', __('Bitte geben sie eine USt-ID Nr ein'));
      }
      if(!is_email($user_email)) {
          red_errors()->add('email_invalid', __('Ungültige E-Mail'));
      }
      if(email_exists($user_email)) {
          red_errors()->add('email_used', __('E-Mail bereits vergeben'));
      }
      if($user_pass == '') {
          red_errors()->add('password_empty', __('Bitte geben sie ein Passwort ein'));
      }
      if($user_pass != $pass_confirm) {
          red_errors()->add('password_mismatch', __('Passwörter sind nicht identisch'));
      }       
      $errors = red_errors()->get_error_messages();    
      if(empty($errors)) {         
          $new_user_id = wp_insert_user(array(
                  'user_login'      => $user_login,
                  'user_pass'           => $user_pass,
                  'user_email'      => $user_email,
                  'first_name'      => $user_first,
                  'last_name'           => $user_last,
                  'user_url'      => $user_website,
                  'user_registered' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                  'role'                => $role
              )
          );
          
          
          wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $new_user_id));
          global $current_user;
          $user = wp_get_current_user();
          $user_id = $user->ID;
         // $user_id = get_current_user_id();
          
          // Checking if user Id exist
           if( !empty( $user_id ) ) {

          // Test
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $user_first );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', $user_last );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $user_email );
               
         // Test
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_first_name', $user_first );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_last_name', $user_last );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_email', $user_email );

         // Test update_user_meta
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', $user_street );
         // Test update_user_meta
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_city', 'Bangalore' );

            } else {
              echo 'User doesnt exist';
            }
          
          if($new_user_id) {
              wp_new_user_notification($new_user_id);              
              wp_set_auth_cookie(get_user_by( 'email', $user_email )->ID, true);
              wp_set_current_user($new_user_id, $user_login);   
              do_action('wp_login', $user_login, wp_get_current_user());            
              wp_redirect(home_url()); exit;
          }         
      }
  }
}
add_action('init', 'red_add_new_user');
function red_errors(){
    static $wp_error; 
    return isset($wp_error) ? $wp_error : ($wp_error = new WP_Error(null, null, null));
}
function red_register_messages() {
    if($codes = red_errors()->get_error_codes()) {
        echo '<div class="red_errors">';
           foreach($codes as $code){
                $message = red_errors()->get_error_message($code);
                echo '<span class="error"><strong>' . __('Error') . '</strong>: ' . $message . '</span><br/>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }   
}
```

My goal was that every time a user is created, the billing/shipping address would also be updated. wp_isert_user() works fine, but the shipping/billing address fields with update_user_meta() do not appear in the user information once the user is created. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `update_user_meta()` is not working because you are trying to use the global current user ID which doesn't exist yet as the Auth cookie is not yet set.

There are some mistakes, unnecessary code and missing things.

You can use [`meta_input` parameter with `wp_insert_user()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/#parameters) arguments to add all desired user metadata as follows:

```php
function red_add_new_user() {
    if ( isset( $_POST["red_user_login"] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['red_csrf'], 'red-csrf') ) {
        $user_login       = isset($_POST["red_user_login"]) ? sanitize_user($_POST["red_user_login"]) : '';
        $user_company     = isset($_POST["red_user_company"]) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_company"]) : '';
        $user_email       = isset($_POST["red_user_email"]) ? sanitize_email($_POST["red_user_email"]) : '';
        $user_first       = isset($_POST["red_user_first"]) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_first"] ) : '';
        $user_last        = isset($_POST["red_user_last"]) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_last"] ) : '';
        $user_street      = isset($_POST["red_user_street"]) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_street"]) : '';
        $user_postcode    = isset($_POST["red_user_postal_code"]) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_postal_code"]) : '';
        $user_country     = isset($_POST["red_user_country"]) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_country"]) : '';
        $user_ustid       = isset($_POST["red_user_ustid"]) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_ustid"]) : '';
        $user_website     = isset($_POST["red_user_website"]) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_website"]) : '';
        $user_phone       = isset($_POST["red_user_phonenumber"]) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_user_phonenumber"]) : '';
        $user_pass        = isset($_POST["red_user_pass"]) ? $_POST["red_user_pass"] : '';
        $pass_confirm     = isset($_POST["red_user_pass_confirm"]) ? $_POST["red_user_pass_confirm"] : '';
        $red_role         = isset($_POST["red_role"]) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST["red_role"] ) : '';  
        
        if ($red_role == (int) filter_var(AUTH_KEY, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ) { 
            $role = "shop_manager"; 
        }  elseif ($red_role == (int) filter_var(SECURE_AUTH_KEY, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ) { 
            $role = "customer"; 
        } elseif ($red_role == (int) filter_var(NONCE_KEY, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ) { 
            $role = "contributor"; 
        } elseif ($red_role == (int) filter_var(AUTH_SALT, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)  ) { 
            $role = "author"; 
        } elseif ($red_role ==  (int) filter_var(SECURE_AUTH_SALT, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ) { 
            $role = "editor"; 
        }   elseif ($red_role == (int) filter_var(LOGGED_IN_SALT, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ) { 
            $role = "administrator"; 
        } else { 
            $role = "subscriber"; 
        }
        
        if(username_exists($user_login)) {
            red_errors()->add('username_unavailable', __('Dieser Benutzername ist bereits vergeben'));
        }
        if(!validate_username($user_login)) {
            red_errors()->add('username_invalid', __('Ungültiger Benutzername'));
        }
        if($user_login == '') {
            red_errors()->add('username_empty', __('Bitte geben sie einen Benutzernamen ein'));
        }
        if($user_company == '') {
            red_errors()->add('company_empty', __('Bitte geben sie eine Firma ein'));
        }
        if($user_street == '') {
            red_errors()->add('street_empty', __('Bitte geben sie eine Straße ein'));
        }
        if($user_postcode == '') {
            red_errors()->add('postal_code_empty', __('Bitte geben sie eine Postleitzahl ein'));
        }
        if($user_country == '') {
            red_errors()->add('country_empty', __('Bitte geben sie ein Land ein'));
        }
        if($user_ustid == '') {
            red_errors()->add('ustid_empty', __('Bitte geben sie eine USt-ID Nr ein'));
        }
        if(!is_email($user_email)) {
            red_errors()->add('email_invalid', __('Ungültige E-Mail'));
        }
        if(email_exists($user_email)) {
            red_errors()->add('email_used', __('E-Mail bereits vergeben'));
        }
        if($user_pass == '') {
            red_errors()->add('password_empty', __('Bitte geben sie ein Passwort ein'));
        }
        if($user_pass != $pass_confirm) {
            red_errors()->add('password_mismatch', __('Passwörter sind nicht identisch'));
        }
            
        $errors = red_errors()->get_error_messages();

        if( empty($errors) ) {         
            $user_id = wp_insert_user( array(
                'user_login'      => $user_login,
                'user_pass'       => $user_pass,
                'user_email'      => $user_email,
                'first_name'      => $user_first,
                'last_name'       => $user_last,
                'user_url'        => $user_website,
                'user_registered' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'role'            => $role,
                'meta_input'      => array(
                    'billing_first_name'  => $user_first,
                    'billing_last_name'   => $user_last,
                    'billing_email'       => $user_email ,
                    'billing_phone'       => $user_phone ,
                    'billing_company'     => $user_company ,
                    'billing_address_1'   => $user_street,
                    'billing_postcode'    => $user_postcode,
                    'billing_country'     => $user_country,
                    'shipping_first_name' => $user_first,
                    'shipping_last_name'  => $user_last,
                    'shipping_email'      => $user_email,
                    'shipping_city'       => 'Bangalore',
                ),
            ) );
            
            // Checking if user has been created
            if( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
                _e("User doesn't exist");
            } else {
                wp_new_user_notification( $user_id );              
                wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true );
                wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);   

                do_action( 'wp_login', $user_login, wp_get_current_user() );    
    
                wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
                exit();
            }         
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'red_add_new_user');
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked.